# Bash variable with :

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am new to bash and am trying to understand a script I have been passed.
Within the script, I have the following variable:

```
site_source="${site_host[$i]}:public_html"
```

Can anyone confirm what the colon means here?
I am needing to change the path stored within this variable to a root path, so had thought that removing the `:public_html` part would achieve this (it doesn't).

Comment: Simple concatenation. `${site_host[$i]} + ":" + "public_html"`

Comment: Did you take a look at what the variable contains after that? Because it might give a very good indication of what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple *concatenation*:

```
${site_host[$i]} + ":" + "public_html"
```

To be not confused with *parameter expansions*

*Parameter Expansion* expands parameters: `$foo`, `$1`. You can use it to perform string or array operations: `"${file%.mp3}"`, `"${0##*/}"`, `"${files[@]: -4}"`. They should **always** be quoted.
See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in man bash.
Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: Good advice about *always quoting*! Note that in *scalar* variable assignments (as in the OP's `site_source=...`), one shouldn't use `"${array[@]}"` which does not make sense as scalar variables can only hold *one* value. One could use `"${array[*]}" which joins the elements with the first character of `$IFS`. You'd use `@` in *array* variable assignments: `array=( "${other_array[@]}" )`, where quotes are even more important than in the scalar assignment case.